# how to add counter in a insertion method wherein it counts the loop of the number you input. (java)

Tags: java, mysql, sorting, for-loop, counter

I'm having a problem in this program, wherein i don't know where to put the counter in my code. It needs to count how many times the loop will count when I put a number. here is my code.

```
public static void sort(int arr[]) {
    int N = arr.length;
    int i, j, temp;


    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        j = i;
        temp = arr[i];

        while (j > 0 && temp < arr[j - 1]) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            j = j - 1;
            ctr++;

        }
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insertion Sort test\n");
    int n, i;
    System.out.println("Enter # of Integer elements");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    int arr[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("\nEnter" + " " + n + " " + "Integer element");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    sort(arr);


    System.out.println("\nElements after Sorting");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();        
}
```

### output:

> Enter # of Integer elements
>
> 5
>
> Enter 5 of Integer elements
>
> 5 4 3 2 1
>
> Elements after Sorting
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

### What should be the output if add count on it.

> Enter # of Integer elements
>
> 5
>
> Enter 5 of Integer elements
>
> 5 4 3 2 1
>
> Elements after Sorting
>
> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> count: 4

### Or

> count: 1
>
> count: 2
>
> count: 3
>
> count: 4
>
> Enter # of Integer elements
>
> 5
>
> Enter 5 of Integer elements
>
> 5 4 3 2 1
>
> Elements after Sorting
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this :
 1. Let sort method returns an integer value. 
 2. Then, initialize 'ctr' variable to 0, at the beginning of sort method.
 3. After sorting, return the 'ctr' variable.
 4. In main function, capture to some integer result of sort method (int counter = sort(arr) ).
 5. Then you only need to print the 'counter' variable.

Answer (score -1):

Just add
      System.out.print("count: "+ i);